# Is it possible to reinstantiate a dbcontext when using a delayed task in .net core api

Tags: c#, .net

I have a controller where the functionality required is to implement a call where two actions are done simultaneously, first we get input and do a call to an external application then respond to the call OK we are working on it and release the caller. When the external application responds, we get the response and save to the db, I am using a task.delay as

Part 1

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResults> ProcessTransaction(Transactions transactions)
{
     // do some processing
     TransactionResults results = new TransactionResults();
     Notify(transactions, results);
     
     return Ok("We are working on it, you will get a notification");
}
```

The delayed task

```
private void Notify(Transactions transactions, TransactionResults results)
{
    Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(t => SendNotification(transactions, results));
}
```

on the SendNotification I am attempting to save the results

```
private void SendNotification(Transactions transactions, TransactionResults results)
{
     // some processing
     _context.Add(results);    // this gives an error context has already been disposed
     _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, or a way to re instantiate the context?

Comment: Why excactly is there a Task.Delay?

Comment: The application is a USSD application, we need the user to close the session to be able to receive the notification, therefore we have to release the call before the user can be notified. That's why we are doing a delay

Comment: I still do not understand, why you need to hold a thread 10 seconds. That has nothing to do with a session.

Comment: For the USSD application we require to send a response to the call so that it can end on the user side and then send a second prompt to the user to complete the transaction, this is a verification where user is requested to pass a PIN to complete the transaction, so the requirement is that you send an OK response, wait for a few seconds (at least 5) then send a confirmation prompt. Its a requirement for that application has no reason programmatically to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do a work around to the problem I am facing, I created an endpoint that I would call once the notification results came back and the data would be saved on the callback not at that particular event. Once the controller has respond with an Ok, the controller is disposed and its difficult to re instantiate it. The call back work around works for now, I will update if I find another way to do it.